# 1 day Yom Tov in Eilat or anywhere in "Israel" outside biblical boundaries

Tags: eretz-yisrael, yom-tov

does anyone know the Halacha regarding one day of yom tov in areas where currently they keep one day , but are not in the "real", biblical borders of eretz yisrael.

Comment: The local Poskim apparently hold one day if that's what they do

Comment: Jonathan S., [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887)! As @DoubleAA is suggesting, your question has some interesting and fraught issues embedded in it. By "where they keep," do you mean "where local rabbinic authorities say to keep" or something more folk-oriented? By "'real'", do you mean "real, according to the rabbinic authority I've consulted" or something else? Depending on what you mean about these two points, the conflict you're asking about could boil down to very different issues. Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: If this question affects you personally, and you're looking for a ruling to determine how to resolve such a conflict in your personal practice, I recommend you [consult your rabbi](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734).

Comment: @DoubleAA I agree with putting this on-hold. Depending on what Jonathan S.'s intent is, this could indeed be a duplicate as you've marked it, or it could be more like "what should I do if I'm going somewhere where the prevailing opinion is different from that promoted by my own rabbi?"